# Vim display compilation errors

Tags: vimrc

I was wondering what plugin or change to my .vimrc file can allow for displaying auto compilation comments like this,

[image]

Comment: I think the term to search would be 'vim linting plugins' - [Ale](https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale) is a popular choice (although some say it's a 'heavy' plugin). See [this link](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Linting) for a brief discussion.

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]! Plugin requests are considered off-topic. A better way to frame your question might be "How can I show compilation errors and lints in vim?" to which there are several good answers, such as `:make` or ALE or coc (LSP).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after doing some digging, it turns out that these are known as "diagnostics", and are available through the built in LSP for c++, or any other language you are coding in. (You just need the corresponding LSP installed). LSP's are conveniently built into Nvim now.